# The perfect app for customizing a 5button mouse?

Tags: macos, keybindings

I'm a new Mac user but I still struggle with ideal mouse settings for a common 5button mouse (I use Logitech MX500 with horizontal scroll and a small travel Razer). I need something from Logi Options, Karabiner Elements, Mos, BetterMouse etc., but it can't be well combined together. I'm willing to pay a lifetime license.
What should this perfect app do:

- Back and Forward buttons working as Back and Forward in most of the apps (Chrome, Finder, ...).
- Scroll acceleration (smooth scrolling).
- Physical horizontal scroll working.
- Doing a horizontal scroll with a modifier key + normal scroll.
- Zoom with modifier key + scroll (ideally not the Accessibility feature, but Cmd +/- key)
- Custom keymapping for different apps (like Commander One which doesn't support Back & Forward button)
- Ideally a modifier to make the scroll slower/faster.

Karabiner Elements may do much of if, but the mouse lags during a fast move. It's a reported bug which hasn't been fixed for perhaps a year. BetterMouse can do it except custom behavior in specified apps as well as Mos. Logi options can't do other things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) will do all this - not sure about the horizontal scroll, never come across it before as a dedicated feature except in the Apple Magic mice, which I don't use.
Normal scroll + Shift is Mac-standard to do a horizontal scroll.
Also not sure about the zoom. You can set chord combos so you may be able to press that into service.  iirc there's a free trial so you can test this kind of thing.

I had an MX518, similar as far as I can tell to the MX500 & SteerMouse served me well for a decade. It doesn't do so well on the MX Master series as Logitech have added some odd firmware which doesn't advertise itself very well to the OS.

Comment: I finally ended up with **SteerMouse**, which is I think superior for configuration. It only lacks smooth scroll (which I don't use anyway), drag when zoomed and has narower speed and acceleration settings for the wheel. It's quite unique for a possibility to simulate 2 different types of zoom - 2finger pinch/zoom and standard Cmd -/+. **BetterMouse** also worked for me with less features, but it was freezing often and caused crashing of WindowServer, so maybe I'll give it a try another time since I've already bought it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm happily using [Mac Mouse Fix](https://mousefix.org/) for some years which can assign actions to Mouse buttons and also greatly improves scrolling smoothness. Horizontal scrolling and zooming via modifier key are standard on macOS AFAIK, but definitely work with this app. However, keymappings for different apps is not supported. Free and open-source.

For maximum configurability, I'd recommend [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/). Originally intended to improve built-in and magic trackpads, it now also extensively supports mouse and keyboard settings and should also be able to do different mappings for different apps. Lifetime license available.

Comment: I finally ended up with **SteerMouse**, which is I think superior for configuration. It only lacks smooth scroll (which I don't use anyway), drag when zoomed and has narower speed and acceleration settings for the wheel. It's quite unique for a possibility to simulate 2 different types of zoom - 2finger pinch/zoom and standard Cmd -/+. **BetterMouse** also worked for me with less features, but it was freezing often and caused crashing of WindowServer, so maybe I'll give it a try another time since I've already bought it.